# Events declared in library are missed in contract ABI

Tags: solidity, etherscan, events, abi, compilation

DYDX contract SoloMargin is firing events like LogTrade, LogSell but they are not provided in ABI.

SoloMargin contract: https://etherscan.io/address/0x1e0447b19bb6ecfdae1e4ae1694b0c3659614e4e#code
Proxy to implementation: https://etherscan.io/address/0x56e7d4520abfecf10b38368b00723d9bd3c21ee1#code

This is bug in solidity compiler or etherscan? Why these events are not listed in ABI?
There should be an option for compiler to include them into ABI?

Comment: I asked something similar https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/84646/sharing-an-event-between-a-contract-and-a-library, but I didn't get any answer.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is possible only by editing ABI manually or edit source code with events definitions and rebuild abi. Github request for change: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/9765#issuecomment-689396725